# How do I download an entire array using web3?

Tags: web3js, synchronization, arrays

I have figured out how to download public data from contracts. This is done by calling `contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address)` and then calling the function of the data. If I have a string called "hello" I can call `contract.hello(function(error, result){console.log(error,result)})`.

If I want to download an array, I can only download a part of the array, and not the entire array. Let's say I have `uint256[16] arr`. I can then download `contract.arr(3, function(error, result){console.log("index 4: "+result)})`.

How can I download all 16 indexes of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By creating a getter function for the array.

Note the following however:

> Due to limitations of the EVM, it is not possible to return dynamic
>   content from external function calls. The function f in 
>   `contract C {function f() returns (uint[]) { ... } }` will return something if
>   called from web3.js, but not if called from Solidity.
>
> The only workaround for now is to use large statically-sized arrays.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.10;

contract Number {
    uint256[5] public array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    function returnArray() public view returns(uint256[5]) {
        return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a Web3.js solution, even though you could setup a getter and make a call via Web3.js. It needs to happen without transacting.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand well, you can create a return function as the follow :

```
uint256[] array;

function returnArray()
 public 
 returns(uint256[]) {
 return array;
}
```

The you can call the function via web3 and process the array, for example split it or just use it. Hope it helps.

Comment: This will only work with fixed-size arrays. 
Solidity can not return dynamic sized arrays.
uint256[5] array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: @Nico It does work. It can't return bi dimensional arrays, ie an array of strings.

Comment: Sorry you are right I forgot the "for external function calls" part :)

"Due to limitations of the EVM, it is not possible to return dynamic content from external function calls. The function f in contract C { function f() returns (uint[]) { ... } } will return something if called from web3.js, but not if called from Solidity.

The only workaround for now is to use large statically-sized arrays."

Comment: What about an array of Structs?